# how to create bins of continuous variable in pandas dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID     value
 1      12.34
 2      102.34
 3      99.43
 4      105
 5      110
 6      110.23
 7      0
 8      0.5
```

I want to create bins of 5 dynamically, following is my desired dataframe

```
ID     value       bin
 1      12.34      10-15
 2      102.34     100-105
 3      99.43      95-100
 4      105        105-110
 5      110        110-115 
 6      110.23     110-115
 7      0          0-5 
 8      0.5        0-5
```

I have tried following but it is not working

```
s1=((df.value//5)*5).min()
s2=((df.value//5+1)*5).max()
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.value,np.arange(s1,s2+5,5))
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 2 new parameters - `labels` and `right=False` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), for labels use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
s1=((df.value//5)*5).min()
s2=((df.value//5+1)*5).max()

bins = np.arange(s1,s2+5,5)
labels = [f'{int(i)}-{int(j)}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
print (df)
   ID   value      bin
0   1   12.34    10-15
1   2  102.34  100-105
2   3   99.43   95-100
3   4  105.00  105-110
4   5  110.00  110-115
5   6  110.23  110-115
6   7    0.00      0-5
7   8    0.50      0-5
```